# PortAudio distorted/clipped/poor sound output

Tags: c++, audio, core-audio, portaudio

I am trying to perform some basic IO within PortAudio. I currently select an audio output and then write some noise to that output via a stream and an `outputCallback` function. The issue is my audio output does not sound how it should. The audio is distorted and clipped. There are clear artefacts in the output.

Here's most of the code so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "portaudio.h"

#define SAMPLE_RATE (44100)
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER (32)

PaStream *outputStream;

// output callback function
static int outputCallback(const void *inputBuffer,
                         void *outputBuffer,
                         unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                         const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo *timeInfo,
                         PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                         void *userData) {
  float *out = (float*)outputBuffer;

  for(int i = 0; i < framesPerBuffer; ++i) {
  float randomValue = -1.0f + static_cast<float>(rand()) / (static_cast<float>(RAND_MAX / 2.0f));
  out[i] = randomValue / 6;
  }

  return paContinue;
}

// starts portaudio
void initPortAudio(PaError err) {
  err = Pa_Initialize();
  if (err != paNoError) {
      std::cout << "Error initializing PortAudio: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
      return;
  }
}

// opens the outputstream
void openOutputStream(PaError err, PaStreamParameters outputParameters) {
  err = Pa_OpenStream(&outputStream, NULL, &outputParameters, SAMPLE_RATE, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER, paNoFlag, outputCallback, NULL);
  if (err != paNoError) {
    std::cout << "Error opening input stream: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
    Pa_CloseStream(inputStream);
    Pa_Terminate();
    return;
  }

  err = Pa_StartStream(outputStream);
  if (err != paNoError) {
    std::cout << "Error starting output stream: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
    Pa_CloseStream(inputStream);
    Pa_CloseStream(outputStream);
    Pa_Terminate();
    return;
  }
}

// closes outputstream
void closeOutputStream(PaError err) {
  err = Pa_StopStream(outputStream);
  if (err != paNoError) {
      std::cout << "Error stopping stream: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
  }

  err = Pa_CloseStream(outputStream);
  if (err != paNoError) {
      std::cout << "Error closing stream: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
  }
}

// ends portaudio
void terminatePortAudio(PaError err) {
  err = Pa_Terminate();
  if (err != paNoError) {
      std::cout << "Error terminating PortAudio: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
      return;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Running Main" << std::endl;

  PaError err;

  initPortAudio(err);


  // All of this stuff is about getting the available output devices and then choosing one
  int numDevices = Pa_GetDeviceCount();
  if(numDevices < 0) {
    std::cout << "Error getting device count: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
    Pa_Terminate();
  }

  std::cout << "Available output devices: " << std::endl;
  for(int i =0; i < numDevices; i++) {
    const PaDeviceInfo *deviceInfo = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(i);
    if(deviceInfo->maxOutputChannels > 0) {
      std::cout << i << ": " << deviceInfo->name << std::endl;
    }
  }

  int selectedDeviceIndex;
  std::cout << "Select an output device by entering its index: ";
  std::cin >> selectedDeviceIndex;

  if (selectedDeviceIndex < 0 || selectedDeviceIndex >= numDevices) {
      std::cout << "Invalid device index" << std::endl;
      Pa_Terminate();
      return 1;
  }

  const PaDeviceInfo *selectedDeviceInfo = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(selectedDeviceIndex);
  if (selectedDeviceInfo->maxOutputChannels == 0) {
      std::cout << "Selected device does not support output" << std::endl;
      Pa_Terminate();
      return 1;
  }

  // the output stream params
  PaStreamParameters outputParameters;
  outputParameters.device = selectedDeviceIndex;
  outputParameters.channelCount = 2;
  outputParameters.sampleFormat = paFloat32;
  outputParameters.suggestedLatency = selectedDeviceInfo->defaultLowOutputLatency;
  outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

  openOutputStream(err, outputParameters); // opening the stream

  getchar();

  bool term = false;
  
  // This stuff just holds the program until the user stops it by pressing enter
  while(!term) {
    int input = getchar();
    if(input == 10) {
    closeOutputStream(err);
    terminatePortAudio(err);
    return 0;
    }
  } 
}
```

So my question is -- What is causing this?

Changing the size of `FRAMES_PER_BUFFER` seems to affect the sound quality. Changing the `outputParameters.sampleFormat` also affects the sound quality. However, all of them still sound wrong, though some combinations are better. I've also tried outputting to different device outputs, and the result is the same.

Comment: you are applying `randomValue` to each sample. Try to just copy values from input to output without such transformations

Comment: please also note that 32 samples buffer size is very small and unlikely will work consistently well

Comment: also currently you don't use `inputBuffer` ever